# Chris Pine Tut Blocks and Procs

Tags: ruby

I understand everything that is happening in the following code except for the `while output` section:

```
1 def doUntilFalse firstInput, someProc
2  input  = firstInput
3  output = firstInput
4  
5  while output
6    input  = output
7    output = someProc.call input
8  end
9  
10  input
11 end
12 
13 buildArrayOfSquares = Proc.new do |array|
14  lastNumber = array.last
15  if lastNumber <= 0
16    false
17  else
18    array.pop                         #  Take off the last number...
19    array.push lastNumber*lastNumber  #  ...and replace it with its square...
20    array.push lastNumber-1           #  ...followed by the next smaller number.
21  end
22 end
23
24 alwaysFalse = Proc.new do |justIgnoreMe|
25  false
26 end
27
28 puts doUntilFalse([5], buildArrayOfSquares).inspect
```

I understand `while` for the most part but for some reason I can't see the forest through the trees in this code.  Could someone explain what is happening in the `while output` part between lines 5 and 8.  I have no doubt it is extremely simple but I've hit a wall with it.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output` will become the return value of the procedure `someProc`, which is in turn passed as a parameter in line #28, as `buildArrayOfSquares`. This, in turn, will return `false` in a certain case; when this happens, the `while` loop will terminate.

In detail, `firstInput` is `[5]`, which becomes the first `input`. We call `buildArrayOfSquares` with `[5]`. Since `5` is not `<= 0`, we take `5` out, put in `25` and `4`.

Next iteration of while, `output` is `[25, 4]`. We continue. Back into `buildArrayOfSquares`. Take `4` off the end; push in `16`, then `3`. `output` is now `[25, 16, 3]`.

Next time, `output` is `[25, 16, 9, 2]`. Then `[25, 16, 9, 4, 1]`. Then `[25, 16, 9, 4, 1, 0]`.

And the next time, `0 <= 0`, and `buildArrayOfSquares` returns `false` into `output`. The loop terminates. `input` is still `[25, 16, 9, 4, 1, 0]`, which is what we presumably wanted.

Comment: That's what I call a comprehensive answer, thank you.  To continue with the trees/forest metaphor, you just took a chainsaw to them.